# How to clear the screen in Visual Studio Code Terminal?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal

How to clear the screen of a Visual Studio Code terminal (Windows)?

When I am in PowerShell, I try `Clear-Host`/`cls`, it seem to clear the terminal, however is enough to scroll up all the text is back...

[image]

Is there a way to *really* clear the terminal in VS-Code?

Comment: It looks like it's buggy behavior (I also see it, but only in PowerShell (Core), not in Windows PowerShell, as of Visual Studio Code 1.86.1). I've update the linked duplicate with the gory details. The simplest workaround is probably to redefine Clear-Host as follows: `function Clear-Host { Write-Host -NoNewLine "$([char]27)[2J$([char]27)[3J$([char]27)[H" }`